# C++ CLI dynamic_cast and multiple inheritance (Windows Forms and Interfaces)

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, c++-cli, multiple-inheritance

The scenario I'm working with looks like this:

```
public interface INativeWindow { ... }
```

is a native window type of interface holding a few required, basic methods to implement in order to have a minimal window support (e.g. minimize, restore, etc.). This is a C# interface belonging to an interfaces project.

Now I want to implement it in a `CLINativeWindow` c++-cli class:

```
public ref class CLINativeWindow: public SWF::NativeWindow, INativeWindow
{ 
 ...
}
```

Lastly, I have another `ref` c++ cli class that has an internal member of the `CLINativeWindow` type and a wrapping property that returns an `INativeWindow^` handle:

```
virtual property INativeWindow^ OwnNativeWindow
                {
                    INativeWindow^ __clrcall get() sealed { return NativeWindow;}
                    void __clrcall set(INativeWindow^ value) { NativeWindow = dynamic_cast<CLINativeWindow^>(value);}
                }
```

The issue here is that the `dynamic_cast` doesn't work, nor does the implicit polymorphic downcast from the property's getter method. If I'm not misinformed, I think I read in several places that in C++ with *normal* pointers, such a blunder really works. Now as an `SWF::NativeWindow` is the classic windows forms native window class (sorry about the unintended alliteration), it should have a virtual method, just as much as the interface does, so no problem for the dynamic cast operator since a polymorphic inheritance is involved. Am I wrong or is this just plain impossible in dotNet C++ CLI?

**EDIT**
additional code:

```
public ref class ExampleForSO
{
  CLINativeWindow^ NativeWindow;


 virtual property INativeWindow^ OwnNativeWindow
                    {
                        INativeWindow^ __clrcall get() sealed { return NativeWindow;}
                        void __clrcall set(INativeWindow^ value) { NativeWindow = dynamic_c

ast<CLINativeWindow^>(value);}
            }
}
```

The errors are from compile time and they state that the conversion/cast cannot be performed for both getter and setter (i.e. cannot convert from B^ to A^ and from B^ to A^)..
**UPDATE**
If the classes are in different files, implementing the property in a header won't do. Implementing it in the separate `.cpp` source file does not cause a compile time error any more and works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no multiple inheritance here. Your `CLINativeWindow` is inheriting from one class: `SWF::NativeWindow`, and it is also implementing `INativeWindow` interface.

You did not provide enough information (what errors are you getting? sample code that can be pasted in VS to reproduce the problem?), but in general there is nothing wrong with the code that you posted.

My guess is that your `NativeWindow` is declared as:

```
CLINativeWindow NativeWindow;
```

without the much needed `^`. Try declaring it as:

```
CLINativeWindow^ NativeWindow;
```

**EDIT**

The following compiles cleanly for me:

```
public interface class INativeWindow
{};

public ref class SWFNativeWindow
{};

public ref class CLINativeWindow : SWFNativeWindow, INativeWindow
{};

public ref class NWHolder
{
public:
    virtual property INativeWindow^ OwnNativeWindow
    {
        INativeWindow^ __clrcall get() sealed { return nativeWindow_; }
        void __clrcall set(INativeWindow^ w) { nativeWindow_ = dynamic_cast<CLINativeWindow^>(w); }
    }

private:
    CLINativeWindow^ nativeWindow_;
};
```

Comment: I did include the handle specifier to the type. I thought in C++-CLI there's no such a concept of "implementing an interface", it's just similar to C++'s "inherit an abstract class" idiom. That's why I specified multiple inheritance in the title. Moreover, is it possible to use a `dynamic_cast` operator for converting an implementation class to its `interface` handle.. when.. the derived class also inherits another class? That's the main issue and I have no clue whatsoever from what I've found on the interweb. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update, instead of the `SWFNativeWindow` ref class, could you try: `System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow` instead? It should be ok since `WndProc` is a virtual protected method.. but for me, that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you for the mock-up code. This is exactly the illustrative scenario I was talking about, all but for a tiny difference: I am using the `System::Windows::Forms::NativeClass` and `SWF` is just a namespace alias. In this case, the cast fails (but it should be working as it did for you). Also, I thought for casts to work with polymorphism, at least one virtual method in the base classes was required.

Comment: Still compiles for me even with `System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow`. Try compiling the sample code here and then compare to the actual code that you have. As for `dynamic_cast`, what you are saying is correct for C++. For managed types in C++/CLI, however, `dynamic_cast` is the equivalent of C# `as` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, it compiles for me as well without any problems, but in an empty project, and in the main cpp file. I guess the problem is somehow elsewhere.